# "new way for loop" in Java, not working, suggestion?

Tags: java, for-loop

this is my problem:
I was trying to use the new for loop in java to print out some strings with doubles. When i compile the code, no errors, but no output, it's like if the for loop isn't working, any help?

the loop it's right in the end, i've printed all the code just to be sure.

```
abstract class Figure3D {

private float[] center;

protected void setCenter(float[] center){this.center = center;}

public abstract double calcolateVolumn();

protected abstract String figureType();

public void printVolumn(){
  System.out.println("Volumn "+ figureType() + calcolateVolumn());
}

}


class Cube extends Figure3D{

private float side;

public Cube(float side, float[] center){
  this.side = side;
  setCenter(center);
}

@Override
protected String figureType(){
    return "Cube ";
}

@Override
public double calcolateVolumn(){
    return side*side*side;
}

}

class Sphere extends Figure3D {

private float radius;

public Sphere(float radius, float[] center){
  this.radius = radius;
  setCenter(center);
}

protected String figureType(){return "Sphere ";}

public double calcolateVolumn(){return ((4f/3f)*radius*radius*radius*3.14f);}

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class TridimensionalFigures {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Figure3D> figures3d = new ArrayList<>(10);
    Sphere sphere;
    Cube cube;

    for (int i = 0; i < figures3d.size(); i++) {
        sphere = new Sphere(i, new float[] {i, i, i});
        figures3d.add(i, sphere);
        i++;
        cube = new Cube(i, new float[] {i, i, i});
    }

    //TOFIX: it needs to print out the volums of all the objects in the arraylist
    for (Figure3D figures : figures3d) {
        System.out.printf("The volumns is: %s %n", figures.calcolateVolumn());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If `figures3d` is nonempty, it will loop. Are you sure it's populated?

Comment: `figures3d` is empty. Read the JavaDoc to know what the *10* in the constructor _really_ means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`figures3d.size()` is 0, so you are not adding anything to the list.

Try changing

```
for (int i = 0; i < figures3d.size(); i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the list is never actually populated.

You set it's initial capacity using the constructor, but that doesn't change the size; it just prevents reallocations later.

Because the size is 0, the populizing loop never runs, so the second loop (in question) is skipped due to the list being empty.

Instead of using the list's size to control the populating loop, extract the magic 10 into its own variable, and loop while `i < tenVariable`.